# How to cycle through number formats?

Tags: excel, vba

I want when I repeatedly press a shortcut, the number in a cell automatically switches formats between:

2020
2020A
2020E
2020A/E
2,020%
2,020x
2,020bps

```vb
Sub Number_Format_Cycle()
Dim x, myFormats
  
myFormats = Array("###0;(###0);-", "###0A;(###0)A;-", "###0E;(###0E);-", "###0A/E;(###0A/E);-", "#,##0.0%;(#,##0.0)%;0.0%", "#,##0.0x;(#,##0.0)x;0.0x", "#,##0bps;(#,##0)bps;0bps")
x = Application.Match(ActiveCell.NumberFormat, myFormats, False)
If IsError(x) Then x = 0
Selection.NumberFormat = myFormats((x Mod (UBound(myFormats) + 1)))
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, what error do you get ? Where ?

Comment: In what way is it not working? An error is thrown, it runs fine but does the wrong thing, etc.? ActiveCell.NumberFormat vs Selection.NumberFormat looks weird.

Comment: It doesn't give an error but instead of cycling through all the formats, it just switches between the first two when you toggle. If i however try and switch the order of the formats so that e.g. 2020E comes first, it givens me the error "Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a **backslash** (`\`) in order to add *character literals*  to make them showing up exactly as typed.
Changing the `myFormats` assignment to the following codeline worked for me:

```
myFormats = Array("###0;(###0);-", "###0\A;(###0)\A;-", "###0\E;(###0\E);-", "###0\A\/\E;(###0\A\/\E);-", "#,##0.0%;(#,##0.0)%;0.0%", "#,##0.0x;(#,##0.0)x;0.0x", "#,##0\bp\s;(#,##0)\bp\s;0\bp\s")
```

Re-Check each number format you intend to add after a test setting against the array elements.

*Caveat: I have to admit that I can't explain the last `\bp\s` format, nevertheless it works.*